# Travis CI. No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself

Tags: java, android, travis-ci

I am building an android studio project (Java) with Firebase as my main database. However, I am now working on travis.ci. Which has proved to be troublesome, now I am experiencing with the issue: No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using adb (add and removal) but to no result.

```
sudo: false

language: android

jdk: oraclejdk8

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew
 - travis_wait mvn install

env:
  global:
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=12 # minutes (2 minutes by default)
android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools # appears twice as per Travis docs

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-28.0.3 # latest build-tools ver sometimes doesn't work well with travis

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-28 # android 9.0 Pie
    - android-22 # another android version used for emulator

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-28
    - extra-android-support
    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22

  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-.+'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'

before_script:
  - android list targets
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - adb wait-for-device
  #- while [[ `adb shell pm path android` == 'Error'* ]]; do sleep 2; done
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"



after_failure:
    - for v in ~/shared/logs/*.log ; do
      echo $v logtail ======================== ; tail -100 $v ;
      done
    - for v in broker middlemanager overlord router coordinator historical ; do
      echo $v dmesg ======================== ;
      docker exec -it druid-$v sh -c 'dmesg | tail -3' ;
      done
```

Comment: Which command times out? You should see it in the travis output. In a php project I had to put
`travis_wait 30 command` which in your case could be
`travis_wait 30 mvn install` if it takes more than 10 minutes (travis ci default timeout)